# How to multiply k 2x2 Matrices by k 2x2 matrices in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 3D tensors in tensorflow, where the two tensors have the shape Kx2x2. The tensors represent a set of 2x2 matrices. Is there a way to multiply the 2x2 matrices in the first tensor with the corresponding matrix in the second so that I get a Kx2x2 tensor in the end?

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) is the correct operator for matrix multiplication. If the dimension of the tensor is over 2, the inner 2 specify the shape of the matrix. Hence the shape of two tensors must be [a<sub>1,</sub> a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>, x, y] and [a<sub>1,</sub> a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>, y, z], respectively ([K, 2, 2] in the OP's case).

**Sample Code**

```
# Suppose X and Y are two tensors of the shape [K, 2, 2]
result = tf.matmul(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do tf.matmul(a,b).

According to the tensorflow documentation,

tf.matmul returns:
A Tensor of the same type as a and b where each inner-most matrix is the product of the corresponding matrices in a and b.

output[..., i, j] = sum_k (a[..., i, k] * b[..., k, j]), for all indices i, j.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul